# Code Coverage Tab Not Showing a Report in Azure DevOps

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops

I have a build pipeline for my .NET Core 2.2 web application which has a .NET Core task for running the tests. However, after running my pipeline and checking the code coverage tab I got the message below.

[image]

[image]

Is there anything missing that I forgot to do or set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below steps to publish the code coverage.

1, First you need to make sure your project reference to nuget package coverlet.msbuild.

```
<PackageReference Include="coverlet.msbuild" Version="2.5.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
```

2, Download the report generator by running a custom dotnet command `install --tool-path . dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool` See below example in yaml format.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: custom
      custom: tool
      arguments: install --tool-path . dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool
    displayName: Install ReportGenerator tool
```

3, Then in your dotnet test task to enable CollectCoverage by adding below arguments:

```
arguments: '/p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutput=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResult\ /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura'
```

4, And install task [Report Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Palmmedia.reportgenerator) to your organization,  and in reportgenerator task specify the reports folder to the CoverletOutput folder reports: `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResult\**\coverage.cobertura.xml` as sepecified in above dotnet test task `/p:CoverletOutput=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResult\`.

See below full example in yaml format:

```
steps:
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    inputs:
      version: 2.2.x 

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: restore
      projects: '**\*.csproj'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: custom
      custom: tool
      arguments: install --tool-path . dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool
    displayName: Install ReportGenerator tool

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Test .NET
    inputs:
      command: test
      projects: '**\*Test*.csproj'
      publishTestResults: false
      arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutput=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResult\ /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura'
    condition: succeededOrFailed()

  - task: reportgenerator@4
    inputs:
      reports: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResult\**\coverage.cobertura.xml'
      targetdir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\coverlet\reports'
      verbosity: 'Verbose'

    condition: succeededOrFailed()
  - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
    displayName: 'Publish code coverage'
    inputs:
      codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
      summaryFileLocation: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\coverlet\reports\Cobertura.xml
      failIfCoverageEmpty: false
      reportDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\coverlet\reports\
    condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need have this settings:

[image]

`--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"` You need to install `coverlet.collector` nuget package.

[image]

Then install report generator: `install --tool-path . dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool`

[image]

Run report generator: `./reportgenerator -reports:$(Agent.TempDirectory)/**/coverage.cobertura.xml -targetdir:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/coverlet/reports -reporttypes:"Cobertura"`

[image]

And publish code coverage to get this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Krzysztof, I did everything you mentioned above but I got this problem on the publish code coverage task:

No code coverage results were found to publish.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/kmadof/devops-manual/tree/master/dotnet-core-on-windows) is my sample project on which I tested it. It works on Linux and Windows host agent. You can try it with this. You can also share your configuration as I did it so I maybe will be able to help you.

Comment: It seems that this solution will not work for my project as the Xplat Code Coverage only supports .NET Core 2.2.3 and above.

Comment: Why do you assume that? Can you show us your steps, one by one. I'm sure we will be able to fix that.